# How do I set the "idea ." command to open IntelliJ IDEA on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

I have Ubuntu 22.04, and I have IntelliJ IDEA installed using Snap package manager.

I want to be able to open a project through terminal with IntelliJ, just like I open a project using `code .` in the project folder to open it using VsCode.

I'm aware that there's a command called `idea .` to open it using IntelliJ, however when I try to use it by using terminal I get the following message

> ```
> Command 'idea' not found, did you mean:
>   command 'idba' from deb idba (1.1.3-7)
> Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
> ```

I also have tried to configure the command-line launcher, by going into "Tools>Create Command-Line Launcher", however I get the following message

> You installed the IDE using Snap package manager, so 'idea' command
> should be already available. If it is not, please make sure
> '/snap/bin' is included in the $PATH variable.

The thing is, `/snap/bin` is included in the $PATH variable, i can find it by using `echo $PATH`